# Supervised rule for organisations

Tags: contacts

When i add an organisation the error message is Sorry an error occurred
Supervised rule for Organization does not exist
I don't seem to be able to add a Rule for Organisations.

Comment: If you go to Contacts - Find and Merge Duplicates what do you see?

Comment: I only see rules for individuals and can't see how to add rules for organisations

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the rules listing page?

Comment: Not sure how to add a screenshot